# activerecord return model with associated model field for csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, export-to-csv

I have 2 models Product and Category

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category

    def self.to_csv(options = {})
        CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
            csv << column_names
            all.each do |ae|
                csv << ae.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
            end
        end
    end
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :products
end

@products = Product.all

@products.to_csv # this line convert product model to csv
```

To generate a csv presentation of all products, instead of showing the category_id foreign key, I want to show the name field of Category model so the csv file is more self explain.

One way I thought about is to use raw sql query instead of activerecord? but this break the to_csv method

How could I do within the Activerecord framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just generating an array to pass through to the css maker, to make a line from, right?  You can build that array however you want.

```
        csv << ["Category"] + column_names
        all.each do |ae|
            csv << [ae.category && ae.category.name] + ae.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
        end
```